# Sending parameters from JSP to spring controller

Tags: spring, model-view-controller, jsp

I am developing a web app using spring MVC. I am passing the parameters from JSP to spring controller in the below format. Like I have to pass two parameters so I am doing

```
<a href="/spring.html?data1=<%=data1 %>?data2=<%=data2 %>"> Hello </a>
```

My assumption is that in the spring controller, I can receive the output as the following

```
data1= request.getAttribute("data1");
data2= request.getAttribute("data2");
```

Is this the correct way to pass the parameters . I have dry run my code many times still my pages gives null pointer so I doubt whether it is because of this . Could you ppl please let me know about this. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

There are at least 2 technical mistakes:

1. You should get request parameters as request parameters, not as request attributes.

   ```java
   data1 = request.getParameter("data1");
   data2 = request.getParameter("data2");
   ```
2. The request parameter separator is `&`, not `?`. The `?` is the request query string separator.

   ```html
   <a href="/spring.html?data1=<%=data1 %>&data2=<%=data2 %>"> Hello </a>
   ```

There's by the way a third mistake, but that's more a design matter. [*Scriptlets* are discouraged since a decade](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3177733/how-to-avoid-java-code-in-jsp-files/3180202#3180202).

Comment: In this how can we pass objects, the problem is I am not able to type case when using request.getParameter

Comment: If data 1 and data 2 are objects then how can I type cast in my controller

Comment: You're making a conceptual mistake. HTML code cannot contain Java objects, but only a sequence of characters. A sequence of characters is in Java represented by a String. So you need to convert them to String and vice versa. Or you could just store them somewhere (database, session, etc) and pass some unique identifier.

Answer (score 0):

If it is Spring MVC controller then your don't need to do call `request.getParameter`. You can just define your method like this and arguments will be auto-populated by MVC framework:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/myRequest", method=RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody
public String handleMyRequest(
        @RequestParam String data1,
        @RequestParam String data2
        ) {
   // your handler code here
   // you will have data1 and data2 automatically populated by Spring MVC
}
```

Comment: Could you please share the corresponding jsp as how to pass an object from there to here. Thank you.

Comment: Your JSP can just have a simple link like: `<a href="/spring.html?data1=<%=data1 %>&data2=<%=data2 %>"> Hello </a>` I suggest reading a little bit about [Spring MVC tutorial](http://static.springsource.org/docs/Spring-MVC-step-by-step/)